# Operations between multiple columns from multiple tables

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models

I am working on a project with Django and I faced an issue on database level when sometimes I need to apply mathematical operations across multiple fields of multiple tables. I did some research and could not find anything exactly suitable to do on Django Model level, so for now I wrote custom raw SQL for my problems. An example would be this:

```
SELECT (s.a_s * tc.value) AS hours
FROM {s} as s, {t_c} as tc
WHERE s.id=%s and tc.key='s_per_tc'
```

My question is: is it possible to sort this kind of issue with Django Model module, or should I keep writing custom queries for such operations? The operations might become more complex involving 3+ tables, etc.

Comment: Can you share your relevant models. Shouldn't `t_c` be joined instead of just selecting items from both tables?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem In this case there is nothing to join on. Essentially `(s.a_s * tc.value)` means (people * hours_per_person). I am essentially storing constants in the database so that the client could modify those. I thought for this situation this is correct approach, but I may be wrong.

Comment: I could technically store a reference to the constants table, however in this case people will always be multiplied by the same constant, hence I did not think this is correct approach even thought it might give me better join possibilities.